# How can I pass external variable with Xidel tool?

Tags: bash, variables, command, xquery, xidel

I have a XQuery expression stored in a file

```
(: file process.xq :) 
declare variable $var external;
...
```

and use it with Xidel.

```
 xidel  --silent --color=never --xml --xquery "$(< process.xq)" my.xml
```

How can I pass such external variable?

Answer (score 0):

it seems be not possible with "external"

but it can be achieved somehow with extra query expression....

```
xidel  --silent --color=never --xml --xquery "foo := bar" --xquery "$(< process.xq)" my.xml
```

and just use the `$foo` as "usual"

```
(: file process.xq :) 
$foo
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no XQuery expert, but at least for `xidel` this is how you declare a variable in a query-file:

```
declare variable $var := "external";

()
```

And don't forget the `()`, or you'll get `err:XPST0003: Unexpected query end`.

Then to load the query-file:

```
$ xidel -s --extract-file=process.xq -e '$var'
#or
$ xidel -s -e @process.xq -e '$var'
external
```